# Launch ngOnInit when click on the row of table

Tags: angular

I have a grid where if I click on the row, then popup appears. In this popup I have two tabs, where one is load this way

```
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <app-user-groups [userId]="userModel.ID_User"></app-user-groups>
    </div>
```

and inside this component i have

```
@Input()
userId: number;


ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserGroups(this.userId);
}
```

and then weird things happen. First of all, just when grid is loaded, then

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserGroups(this.userId);
}
```

also launch and userId is set to undefined. How to make that ngOnInit is only launch when I click on the row of my table ?

Comment: import AfterViewInit in your component and use ngAfterViewInit() {}

Comment: you can't control when `ngOnInit` is called since it's part of change detection process, read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the userId are loaded asynchronously, so when the view renders initially, the this.userId is undefined. 
You are basically just seeing the onInit call based on the original value (undefined).

Try like this:

```
@Input()
userId: number;


ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getUserGroups(this.userId);
}
```